# Making "Include" files, global scoping, and more work

Tags: scope, include, applescript, global

I have an AppleScript that needs to have a customized version to be run on hundreds of machines, each machine having a different version of the script.  My thought was to separate the customized details into one file, and then have a "codebase script" (CodeBaseTest.scpt) file that would be included on them. That way, I could maintain one codebase file more easily.

Because I don't know the version of macOS running (and it may be as far back as 10.13), I need to keep things super simple. Furthermore, because they won't have script libraries installed, I can't use that mechanism for a codebase lib. That also rules out the third party tools, I believe, that make it easier to produce scripts with includes (whether a library, or something like Script Debugger).

So, I've gone ahead and split it to 2 scripts:

**first.last.scpt** << customized for each machine
**CodeBaseTest.scpt** << is copied to the same folder as first.last.scpt so it's in the same folder

To make this work, and to make it easy to test new versions of code in the code base, I wanted to make the "on run" handler the same in both files -- but this isn't a must, just made it easier to do things.

Also to make it work, I had to remove all the properties and move to globals with declarations and then a set to make the defaults work.

The problem is that the scripts are not seeing variables that are clearly defined as globals.

There are two sets of these two files below -- a short set, and a set that has a ton of debug code in the two files here (which will make the errors very obvious if you run them).

**Short set first**

**first.last-test.scpt here:**

```
on run
    global myPath, myName, scriptFileExtension, myLibFilename, myLib
    set myPath to (path to me) as text
    set myName to ((name of me) as text)
    set scriptFileExtension to ".scpt"
    set myLibFilename to "CodeBaseTest" & scriptFileExtension
    
    if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is not myLibFilename then
        set myLib to load script (text 1 through ((length of myPath) - (length of (myName & scriptFileExtension))) of myPath & myLibFilename) as alias
    else if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is myLibFilename then
        set myLib to me
    else
        set fullErrorMsg to "Critical error assigning myLib or loading script. Script terminating. (main on run handler)" & return
        log fullErrorMsg
        display dialog fullErrorMsg
    end if
    
    (*  —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        Assumptions that need to be defined early on… and are done so in initializeGlobals()
        So that they can be used from either the user script (e.g., first.last.scpt) or test data
        within code base script (i.e., OutlookCodeBase.scpt). First a check which file we're in.
        —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        *)
    
    initializeGlobals() of myLib
    
    -- Account to copy to. If empty, defaults to first account in AcctsToAddList.
    global theDestAcctParams, theDestAcctParamNames
    set theDestAcctParams to {}
    set theDestAcctParamNames to {}
    
    (*  —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        Accounts to Add: Custom User Account Parameters -- defined for each user
        —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        *)
    global AcctsToAddList
    set AcctsToAddList to {¬
        {"Field1", "Field2", "Field3"}, ¬
        {"A", "B", "C"}, ¬
        {"D", "E", "F"}, ¬
        {EndOfListMarker}}
    
    -- Main Script, and supporting routines, are executed by a routine in the OutlookCodeBase.scpt file
    if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is not myLibFilename then
        mainScript() of myLib
    else
        mainScript()
    end if
    
end run
```

`

**and CodeBaseTest.scpt (with debug code) here:**

```
on initializeGlobals()
    -- Additional logging takes place with the debugFlag set to true
    global debugFlag
    set debugFlag to true as boolean
    
    global BlankUserPassword, EndOfListMarker
    set BlankUserPassword to "" -- should remain blank and not seen
    set EndOfListMarker to "ENDOFLIST"
    
end initializeGlobals

on mainScript()
    
    (*  —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        Log the time, so we know which run this is...
        —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        *)
    --if debugFlag then log "This run started at: " & (time string of (current date))
    
    -- if theDestAcctParams is empty, copy first account from AcctsToAddList
    if number of items in theDestAcctParams is 0 then
        if number of items in AcctsToAddList is greater than 1 then
            if debugFlag is true then log "theDestAcctParams is empty. copying 2nd item from AcctsToAddList"
            set theDestAcctParams to item 2 of AcctsToAddList
        else
            log "!!! ERROR: not enough items in AcctsToAddList to copy"
        end if
        if debugFlag is true then log "theDestAcctParams is not empty."
    end if
    
end mainScript

on run
    global myPath, myName, scriptFileExtension, myLibFilename, myLib
    set myPath to (path to me) as text
    set myName to ((name of me) as text)
    set scriptFileExtension to ".scpt"
    set myLibFilename to "CodeBaseTest" & scriptFileExtension
    
    if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is not myLibFilename then
        set myLib to load script (text 1 through ((length of myPath) - (length of (myName & scriptFileExtension))) of myPath & myLibFilename) as alias
    else if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is myLibFilename then
        set myLib to me
    else
        set fullErrorMsg to "Critical error assigning myLib or loading script. Script terminating. (main on run handler)" & return
        log fullErrorMsg
        display dialog fullErrorMsg
    end if
    
    (*  —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        Assumptions that need to be defined early on… and are done so in initializeGlobals()
        So that they can be used from either the user script (e.g., first.last.scpt) or test data
        within code base script (i.e., OutlookCodeBase.scpt). First a check which file we're in.
        —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        *)
    
    initializeGlobals() of myLib
    
    -- Account to copy to. If empty, defaults to first account in AcctsToAddList.
    global theDestAcctParams, theDestAcctParamNames
    set theDestAcctParams to {}
    set theDestAcctParamNames to {}
    
    (*  —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        Accounts to Add: Custom User Account Parameters -- defined for each user
        —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        *)
    global AcctsToAddList
    set AcctsToAddList to {¬
        {"Field1", "Field2", "Field3"}, ¬
        {"A", "B", "C"}, ¬
        {"D", "E", "F"}, ¬
        {EndOfListMarker}}
    
    -- Main Script, and supporting routines, are executed by a routine in the OutlookCodeBase.scpt file
    if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is not myLibFilename then
        mainScript() of myLib
    else
        mainScript()
    end if
    
end run
```

Anyone have any idea why this isn't working?  I'm sure (and hopeful) that I'm doing something stupid ... after all, I am coding during a migraine ... but I have to get this done today!

Thanks for reading (and even more if you can help)!
Neil

**================================================================
The below is just the same scripts, but the set with all the extra debug code:
================================================================**

**first.last-test.scpt here:**

```
on run
    global actionsHistory
    set actionsHistory to ""
    
    global myPath, myName, scriptFileExtension, myLibFilename, myLib
    set myPath to (path to me) as text
    set myName to ((name of me) as text)
    set scriptFileExtension to ".scpt"
    set myLibFilename to "CodeBaseTest" & scriptFileExtension
    
    set actionsHistory to actionsHistory & return & return & ¬
        "• " & ("hello world from " & myName)
    display dialog ("hello world from " & myName)
    
    if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is not myLibFilename then
        set myLib to load script (text 1 through ((length of myPath) - (length of (myName & scriptFileExtension))) of myPath & myLibFilename) as alias
    else if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is myLibFilename then
        set myLib to me
    else
        set fullErrorMsg to "Critical error assigning myLib or loading script. Script terminating. (main on run handler)" & return
        log fullErrorMsg
        display dialog fullErrorMsg
        set actionsHistory to actionsHistory & return & return & ¬
            "• " & fullErrorMsg
    end if
    
    (*  —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        Assumptions that need to be defined early on… and are done so in initializeGlobals()
        So that they can be used from either the user script (e.g., first.last.scpt) or test data
        within code base script (i.e., OutlookCodeBase.scpt). First a check which file we're in.
        —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        *)
    try
        initializeGlobals() of myLib
        (*
        if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is not myLibFilename then
            initializeGlobals() of myLib
        else
            initializeGlobals()
        end if
    *)
    on error errorStr number errorNum partial result resultList
        set fullErrorMsg to ("Error is: " & errorStr & return & "Error number: " & errorNum & return & "Result List: " & resultList as text) ¬
            & return & "Critical error initializing globals. Script terminating. (attempt to call initializeGlobals() in " & myName & ")"
        log fullErrorMsg
        display dialog fullErrorMsg
        set actionsHistory to actionsHistory & return & return & ¬
            "• " & fullErrorMsg
    end try
    
    -- Account to copy to. If empty, defaults to first account in AcctsToAddList.
    global theDestAcctParams, theDestAcctParamNames
    set theDestAcctParams to {}
    set theDestAcctParamNames to {}
    
    (*  —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        Accounts to Add: Custom User Account Parameters -- defined for each user
        —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        *)
    global AcctsToAddList
    set AcctsToAddList to {¬
        {"Field1", "Field2", "Field3"}, ¬
        {"A", "B", "C"}, ¬
        {"D", "E", "F"}, ¬
        {EndOfListMarker}}
    
    -- Main Script, and supporting routines, are executed by a routine in the CodeBaseTest.scpt file
    if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is not myLibFilename then
        mainScript() of myLib
    else
        mainScript()
    end if
    
    display dialog "Action history is: " & return & return & actionsHistory
    
end run
```

**and CodeBaseTest.scpt (with debug code) here:**

```
on initializeGlobals()
    display dialog ("hello world from initializeGlobals() in CodeBaseTest.scpt")
    try
        -- Additional logging takes place with the debugFlag set to true
        global debugFlag
        set debugFlag to true as boolean
        
        global BlankUserPassword, EndOfListMarker
        set BlankUserPassword to "" -- should remain blank and not seen
        set EndOfListMarker to "ENDOFLIST"
        
    on error errorStr number errorNum partial result resultList from badObject to expectedType
        set fullErrorMsg to (("Error is: " & errorStr & return * " Error number: " & errorNum & return ¬
            & "in script: " & myName & return ¬
            & "Result List: " & resultList as text) & return ¬
            & "badObject: " & badObject as text) & return ¬
            & "Coercion failure: " & expectedType
        log fullErrorMsg
        display dialog fullErrorMsg
        set actionsHistory to actionsHistory & return & return & ¬
            "• " & fullErrorMsg
    end try
    
    display dialog ("In routine " & "initializeGlobals" & " (end)" & " in " & myName & " with debugFlag = " & debugFlag)
end initializeGlobals

on mainScript()
    display dialog ("hello world from mainScript() in CodeBaseTest.scpt")
    
    (*  —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        Log the time, so we know which run this is...
        —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        *)
    try
        display dialog ("In routine " & "mainScript" & " (start)" & " with debugFlag = " & debugFlag)
        if debugFlag then log "This run started at: " & (time string of (current date))
    on error errorStr number errorNum partial result resultList from badObject to expectedType
        set fullErrorMsg to ("Error is: " & errorStr & return & " Error number: " & errorNum & return ¬
            & "Result List: " & (resultList as text) & return ¬
            & "badObject: " & (badObject as text) & return ¬
            & "Coercion failure: " & expectedType)
        log fullErrorMsg
        display dialog fullErrorMsg
        set actionsHistory to actionsHistory & return & return & ¬
            "• " & fullErrorMsg
    end try
    
    -- if theDestAcctParams is empty, copy first account from AcctsToAddList
    try
        if number of items in theDestAcctParams is 0 then
            if number of items in AcctsToAddList is greater than 1 then
                if debugFlag is true then log "theDestAcctParams is empty. copying 2nd item from AcctsToAddList"
                set theDestAcctParams to item 2 of AcctsToAddList
            else
                log "!!! ERROR: not enough items in AcctsToAddList to copy"
            end if
            if debugFlag is true then log "theDestAcctParams is not empty."
        end if
    on error errorStr number errorNum partial result resultList from badObject to expectedType
        set fullErrorMsg to ("Error is: " & errorStr & return & " Error number: " & errorNum & return ¬
            & "Result List: " & (resultList as text) & return ¬
            & "badObject: " & (badObject as text) & return ¬
            & "Coercion failure: " & expectedType)
        log fullErrorMsg
        display dialog fullErrorMsg
        set actionsHistory to actionsHistory & return & return & ¬
            "• " & fullErrorMsg
    end try
    
end mainScript

on run
    global actionsHistory
    set actionsHistory to ""
    
    global myPath, myName, scriptFileExtension, myLibFilename, myLib
    set myPath to (path to me) as text
    set myName to ((name of me) as text)
    set scriptFileExtension to ".scpt"
    set myLibFilename to "CodeBaseTest" & scriptFileExtension
    
    set actionsHistory to actionsHistory & return & return & ¬
        "• " & ("hello world from " & myName)
    display dialog ("hello world from " & myName)
    
    if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is not myLibFilename then
        set myLib to load script (text 1 through ((length of myPath) - (length of (myName & scriptFileExtension))) of myPath & myLibFilename) as alias
    else if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is myLibFilename then
        set myLib to me
    else
        set fullErrorMsg to "Critical error assigning myLib or loading script. Script terminating. (main on run handler)" & return
        log fullErrorMsg
        display dialog fullErrorMsg
        set actionsHistory to actionsHistory & return & return & ¬
            "• " & fullErrorMsg
    end if
    
    (*  —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        Assumptions that need to be defined early on… and are done so in initializeGlobals()
        So that they can be used from either the user script (e.g., first.last.scpt) or test data
        within code base script (i.e., OutlookCodeBase.scpt). First a check which file we're in.
        —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        *)
    try
        initializeGlobals() of myLib
        (*
        if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is not myLibFilename then
            initializeGlobals() of myLib
        else
            initializeGlobals()
        end if
    *)
    on error errorStr number errorNum partial result resultList
        set fullErrorMsg to ("Error is: " & errorStr & return & "Error number: " & errorNum & return & "Result List: " & resultList as text) ¬
            & return & "Critical error initializing globals. Script terminating. (attempt to call initializeGlobals() in " & myName & ")"
        log fullErrorMsg
        display dialog fullErrorMsg
        set actionsHistory to actionsHistory & return & return & ¬
            "• " & fullErrorMsg
    end try
    
    -- Account to copy to. If empty, defaults to first account in AcctsToAddList.
    global theDestAcctParams, theDestAcctParamNames
    set theDestAcctParams to {}
    set theDestAcctParamNames to {}
    
    (*  —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        Accounts to Add: Custom User Account Parameters -- defined for each user
        —-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-—-
        *)
    global AcctsToAddList
    set AcctsToAddList to {¬
        {"Field1", "Field2", "Field3"}, ¬
        {"A", "B", "C"}, ¬
        {"D", "E", "F"}, ¬
        {EndOfListMarker}}
    
    -- Main Script, and supporting routines, are executed by a routine in the CodeBaseTest.scpt file
    if (myName & scriptFileExtension) is not myLibFilename then
        mainScript() of myLib
    else
        mainScript()
    end if
    
    display dialog "Action history is: " & return & return & actionsHistory
    
end run
```

Comment: Note that the scope of a global variable is limited to the handler or script it is declared in. - see the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_variables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH223-SW1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. AppleScript’s `global` is an absolute menace; one of the language’s (many) design flaws. Avoid. You will tie yourself in knots by using it. Instead, use `property` for all non-local variables. Properties are strictly scoped to the script that declares them. If script B needs to access properties and handlers from script A, script B should import script A and assign it to a property: `use ALib : script "ALib"` (or `property ALib : load script (POSIX file "/path/to/ALib")` if you’re doing it old-style).
2. You *can* use AppleScript’s native library support. [Here is the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_script_objects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH207-SW13). See #1 and #2. Save your customized scripts as either a Script Editor/Script Debugger `.app` applet or as a `.scptd` file, and put all its libraries inside that bundle. When the main app/script finds a `use` statement, it will search for those embedded libraries first. You don’t have to install any libraries in `/Library/Script Libraries` or `~/Library/Script Libraries`.
3. Where you do need to share some properties/handlers between several scripts, put them into their own library and have the other scripts import that. You want to create a nice tree-shaped dependency structure, e.g. shared lib A is imported by libs B and C, which are imported by scripts D, E, and F. You want to avoid a cat’s cradle of dependencies where every script imports every other script (e.g. A imports B and C; B imports A and C; C imports A and B) and each script manipulates the others ad-hoc. That will create an incomprehensible tangle that even you can’t understand, never mind quickly and easily debug. (Especially avoid circular dependencies: e.g. A imports B, B imports C, C imports A again. Those are a nightmare to do right, and are generally a sign that you’ve divided up your program badly.)

…

Anyway, that’s the techie bit summarizing **How** to structure your code. Read on if you want to understand the **Why**.

---

Programming is *not* about creating complexity. It’s about *minimizing and managing* that complexity successfully. Handlers and libraries are two of the tools you use for that. Use them well, and you will smash the problem. Use them ineffectively, complexity will smash you.

I’m guessing you’re a self-taught AppleScripter, not a college-trained Computer Science graduate (although plenty of those jokers can’t program for toffee). Either way, your scripts have now reached a level of ambition, size, and complexity where your old “bodge it till it works” AppleScript hacking skills no longer succeed like they used to. Spaghetti hacking skills are great for quickly making simple automations that do the job, but once you get into hundreds and thousands of lines of code those same skills will bury you alive.

You need to go learn yourself a little bit of Computer Science now, because CS ran into and figured out techniques for managing code complexity 50 years ago.

Here’s two words for you to start researching: “coupling” and “cohesion”.

Good code has low coupling and high cohesion; bad code has the opposite.

BTW, I wrote a *very* brief intro to software design in ch 29 of *Learn AppleScript, 3rd edition*, which you might or might not find helpful. (Ignore the section about making libraries in the Script Objects chapter though: that’s all obsolete since AS introduced native library support.)

Beyond that, I *strongly* recommend you buy a cheap copy of Steve McConnell’s *Code Complete, 1st edition* off eBay. That book covers just about every Do and Don’t of architecting software. However, *don’t* read CC cover-to-cover (you will never take it in). Instead, put it on your bookshelf until you start struggling with some aspect of your program’s design. When you do, take it down, read through the Table of Contents, and when you find a chapter topic that sounds like it might relate to your problem, go read just that chapter. You may need to hop back and forth a few times between your code and the book, but eventually what it’s saying will start to make sense.

…

One more thing:

The real payoff to learning yourself some CS is not simply that your scripts work reliably and be a  relatively fast and pain-free pleasure to code. That is lovely to achieve, but it is not *your* [killer USP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_selling_proposition).

What mastering CS stuff does is equip you to run circles around professional college-trained programmers who know lots about programming but possess *none* of your years of expert knowledge, insight, and experience inside your specialist profession (e.g. print industry). Being skilled in *both* is a [force multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_multiplication).

A programmer who understands their problem domain at a deep, expert level—who can talk to users in those users’ own language, and treat them as full peers and collaborators in building their solutions—is like discovering a unicorn amongst a herd of donkeys. (Not all customers will appreciate this but for those who do you can blow their socks off.) Takes a few years to get up to this level, but as you do remember to increase your [rates](https://twitter.com/TheKingAdRob/status/1563303483641511937) accordingly!

Comment: First, thank you for taking the time to write something so in depth.  To answer your question, I do have a degree in CS -- and the complexity has arisen because I so badly want a #include statement in AppleScript, and it's caused me to go off the rails to accommodate!

The issue that I'm facing is that I really don't want to create bundles and apps, just want to export (as text from FileMaker) the customized script for each user, and was hoping to just do an "include" in the appropriate places to, as you said, keep things simple and tree like (totally agree -- what you saw is what AS forced)

Comment: I had everything as properties -- but because properties have to come before the "on run" handler, I was struggling to include some before some other properties (the custom ones specific to a user) were defined.  That's why I moved to globals -- would strongly prefer properties!

Comment: So, I'd like to simplify the question since I'm still unable to get an external library to load even with your links.  The customized piece needs some things defined as properties ahead of the part that it has as customized (e.g., #include EarlyDefinedProperties.scpt or .scptd ... either is fine). That file will be at the same  location as the first.last.scpt file that needs to include it.

Comment: Then, a second file needs to be included ... WorkRoutines.scpt (or d)... as some of what it needs is defined in first.last.scpt (that's why it can't be in EarlyDefinedProperties).

Assuming that EarlyDefinedProperties and WorkRoutines are in the same folder as first.last.scpt ... how do I do the includes, specifically?

Comment: “I do have a degree in CS”—Even better, you’ll already know all about coupling and cohesion and stuff like that. Re. the ordering of property declaration vs use: AS statically binds *variable names* in a single pass, thus as in C the declarations must come first. e.g. `property foo : 1` must appear before `set foo to foo + 1`, or the latter will assume `foo` is a local variable. Commands and references are dynamically bound though, so are not order dependent. (e.g. `set my foo to my foo + 1` can appear above the property declaration.)

Comment: While you’re figuring out the right way to do AS imports, it’d help if you create 3 new scripts: 2 libraries and the main script which uses them. For imports, e.g. `use WorkRoutines : script "WorkRoutines"`. (That is equivalent to `import WorkRoutines from './WorkRoutines.mjs'`. AS does not do C-style `#include` where everything ends up smooshed in a single namespace; ignoring that `global` mis-feature, scripts’ namespaces are strictly maintained). Add bare minimum of code: 1 property + 1 handler in each library, and a `run` handler in the main script that uses those. /1

Comment: Put the 2 libraries in `~/Library/Script Libraries`. Once that code is working, add some more test code so one library also imports and uses the other.  Once that’s working, re-save the main script as a bundle (`.app` is easiest to start), and move the libraries out of `~/Library/Script Libraries` and into `Main.app/Contents/Resources/Script Libraries`. Once you’ve got that working, you know how to architect the real thing. /2

Comment: The main pain you’ll run into is that AS needs to find the library files in order to compile a script that uses them. (That is because the AS devs stupidly allowed AS libraries to have their own SDEF dictionaries, and AS can’t compile any code until it has searched for and found **all** SDEFs that code might need.) If you need to “trick” AS into compiling your main script successfully, just stick some dummy empty `WorkRoutines.scpt` etc. files into your own `~/Library/Script Libraries`; AS will see they don’t have SDEFS and then compile your main script normally. /3

Comment: Working the problem step by step, if you do run into a problem it should be easy to narrow down the cause. If you can’t figure it yourself, post your test scripts here, with a screenshot of your folder structures and whatever error messages you’re getting, and folks here can have a look. (While you could append it to your original post, I suggest just starting a new, clean Question; your original question about how to do global #includes in AS is basically answered: Don’t Do That.) Good luck—and believe it or not AS’s library loader is actually one of its *less* borked features! :p /fin

Answer (score 0):

I so appreciate the explanations -- and it's clear that if I want to spend the next couple of days figuring out how to do something useful, I think at the end of the day, there's too much here to figure out.

Given this is a project that will live for no more than a month more, and that I need to start using today, I'm going to give up -- and not try to structure the files so that I can maintain it more easily.

Instead, I'll have one long script for each first.last.scpt ... and no "include" files at all.  I'll just maintain the code in FileMaker where I'll be creating the different "personalized" versions for each person.

Thank you SO much for the explanation -- it allowed me to make an informed decision.

Comment: I empathise with the dilemma of wanting to get something working right weighed against how much it's actually going to end up being used.  has's approach is the best one generally speaking, but if you just wanted to get it working now with minimal effort, then "import" one script (e.g. `b.applescript`) into another script (e.g. `a.applescript`) by having `a.applescript` declare `property b : run script "/path/to/b.applescript"` (or via `set b to ...`), but make sure that the return value of `b.applescript` is itself, i.e. `b`'s `run` handler should only set the globals and `return me`.

Comment: Then you can access `b`'s globals from `a.applescript` by way of `b's actionHistory` and `b's myName`.  This is not as robust a method as invoking `use ...`, but it's possibly the simplest, and the only one that'll allow one to work with AppleScripts in text format rather than compiled scripts (which is what I mostly did).  But Has is also right to deter you from using globals, not so much because they're difficult to grasp, but because they're sloppy and there's (usually) never a real need to employ them over properties or passing data through parameters to handlers.

Comment: “Git It Done” works too!

Comment: CJK, I think I tried that at one point, but the issue is that I need to define some "constants" (whether as a property [preferred] or a global) that are used right inside BOTH the a.scpt and b.scpt.  Since properties have to come first, before any handlers, I tried globals.

In the end, I've given up (spent too much time that I didn't have on this, and it's a shorter term solution) -- and just will use the single file approach with everything in it.  I'm just going to use FileMaker to export the whole script customized for each person.

If we need long term, I'll move to import the data